# Getting error 6:Overflow on arithmetic with variants

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that returns a variant data type and in one section of my code I'm doing arithmetic with the returned values.  It sometimes, but not always, returns 6:Overflow.

```
lgRow = lgRow + 1
sgLabel = "Shares Outstanding (current, current)"
If wsUser.Cells(lgRow, 1) <> sgLabel Then
    wsUser.Cells(lgRow, 1) = sgLabel
End If
Dim lgSharesOutstanding As Long
MsgBox "mktCap is " & ProfileValue(sgTickerSymbol, "mktCap") & ", price is " & ProfileValue(sgTickerSymbol, "price")

lgSharesOutstanding = ProfileValue(sgTickerSymbol, "mktCap") / ProfileValue(sgTickerSymbol, "price")
```

The error occurs on this line.

```
lgSharesOutstanding = ProfileValue(sgTickerSymbol, "mktCap") / ProfileValue(sgTickerSymbol, "price")
```

[image]
[image]

So obviously not a divide by 0 error.

For completeness, ProfileValue is dumped below...

```
Function ProfileValue(ticker_in As String, label_in As String) As Variant
Dim sProcedureName As String
sProcedureName = "ProfileValue"
On Error GoTo 0

Dim sgProfileSheetname As String
sgProfileSheetname = ticker_in & PROFILE_WORKSHEETNAME
If Not DoesSheetExist(ActiveWorkbook, sgProfileSheetname) Then
    err.Raise ERROR_USER_ERROR, sProcedureName, _
        "Profile for " & ticker_in & " not found."
End If
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(sgProfileSheetname)

Dim rgLabelRange As Range
Dim lgBottomLabelRow As Long
lgBottomLabelRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rgLabelRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lgBottomLabelRow, 1))

Dim rgThisCell As Range
Set rgThisCell = FindLabel(label_in, rgLabelRange)

ProfileValue = rgThisCell.Offset(, 1).Value
End Function 'ProfileValue
```

What's the simplest way to bypass this error?  I checked, and my VBA instance is 64bit, so there really shouldn't be any data overflow error.

The following is the result of further testing since the question was first posted...

When choosing "About Excel", it says 64 bit...
[image]

I dug up some VBA code off the internet to check for 64 bit.  Code is...

```
    Sub bitness()
        MsgBox "Is it 64 bit???:" & Is64bitVba
    End Sub
    
    'Returns True if the user is running 64-bit *VBA*
    '   This is *NOT* the same as the Windows bitness;
    '   64-bit Windows can (and often does) run 32-bit VBA
    Public Function Is64bitVba() As Boolean
      Is64bitVba = False
        #If Win64 Then
            Is64bitVba = True
        #End If

End Function 'Is64BitVba
```

[image]

However, my long variables are not accepting numbers beyond what a 32bit version would accept.  When I even put such a number in VBA, VBA puts a # after the number (to convert it to double I believe).

```
Dim la1 As Long: Dim la2 As Long
'Let la1 = va
Let la1 = 2147483647
Let la2 = 2147483648#
```

VBA forced the # after the number; AND when I run the line, it produces the overflow error.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What datatype is `lgSharesOutstanding`?

Comment: lgSharesOutstanding is Long.  Also see more work posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  I need to use the LongLong datatype, and not just the Long datatype.  I thought the Long datatype automatically changed to 8 bytes in 64bit systems.  It doesn't.